# java.io.NotSerializableException in Spark Streaming with enabled checkpointing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

code below:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext
    val sec = Seconds(3)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, sec)
    ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint")
    val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("a","b","c"))
    val inputDStream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, rdd)

    inputDStream.transform(rdd => {
        val buf = ListBuffer[String]()
        buf += "1"
        buf += "2"
        buf += "3"
        val other_rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(buf)   // create a new rdd
        rdd.union(other_rdd)
    }).print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

and throw exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@5626e185)
    - field (class: com.mirrtalk.Test$$anonfun$main$1, name: ssc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)
    - object (class com.mirrtalk.Test$$anonfun$main$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$1$$anonfun$apply$21, name: cleanedF$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$1$$anonfun$apply$21, <function2>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$2$$anonfun$5, name: cleanedF$3, type: interface scala.Function2)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$transform$2$$anonfun$5, <function2>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream, name: transformFunc, type: interface scala.Function2)
```

when I remove code ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint"), the application can work well, but I need enable checkpoint.

how to fix this issue when **enable checkpoint**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move context initialization and configuration tasks outside `main`:

```scala
object App {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("foo").setMaster("local"))
  val sec = Seconds(3)
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, sec)
  ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoint") // enable checkpoint

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "c"))
    val inputDStream = new ConstantInputDStream(ssc, rdd)

    inputDStream.transform(rdd => {
      val buf = ListBuffer[String]()
      buf += "1"
      buf += "2"
      buf += "3"
      val other_rdd = ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(buf)
      rdd.union(other_rdd) // I want to union other RDD
    }).print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the issue the fact that a `StreamingContext` can't be serialized, and he's using it inside a transformation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This was my first thought but it is not used in transformation (it is used only at the stream level) so it is not direct issue. It looks like the problem is more subtle here with .StreamingContext being dragged down during checkpoint.

Comment: Is `transform` invoked on the driver side or the worker side?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Driver side. And it [is using contexts internally anyway](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a95252823e09939b654dd425db38dadc4100bc87/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L673-L683).

Comment: Since `transform` take an `RDD` as input, it logically cannot be run on the worker. You can only access an `RDD` on the driver.

Comment: @zero323 Thank you very much! It works well now! But I don't know what's the difference of context initialization and configuration tasks outside `main` or inside `main`?

Comment: Is this way suitable for Production Environment?

Comment: @zero323 Could you tell me what's the difference of outside `main` and inside `main`? I can't find any documents or posts to describe this situation. I really want to know. please!

Comment: `main`, as any other function is just an object, here of type `Function1[Array[String], Unit] `. So every value in its body is its member. In second case it is a member of enclosing object.

Comment: @zero323  Thanks again! I think I can probably understand.

Comment: I have a very similar issue in Java code, I do have Spark Object initiated in a different class and not in the same class, but I still see this error. Please have a look:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747725/sparkstreaming-creating-rdd-and-doing-union-in-a-transform-operation-with-ssc-ch?noredirect=1#comment70688308_41747725